# MinionPro Integral no longer appears as it should

Tags: minionpro

I used to be able to use `MinionPro` package with the option of using the integral sign `minionint` from the MinionPro font instead of the MnSymbol. Somehow, I must have messed up something as now the integral sign looks like this :

[image]

On a different PC (let's call it B), the integral sign is correctly rendered.
When I look into the log file when running a MWE I  see that the file `mn-integral.enc` is called up in the B laptop, but not in the other one. Further, the file `psfontst1.map` has no record of that .enc file in the descriptions. However, it appears correctly in the folder

> c:/Program files/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro.

[Edit] With MiKTeX2.9 on Win7x64, Up to date [end edit] I did run `initexmf --mkmaps` after refreshing the file database. And `updmap` does have the Map MinionPro line.

What did I do wrong?
How can I make the .enc file be read and used on the first PC (PC "A")?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[minionint]{MinionPro} % fourierbb: fourier Black board fonts
%  [minionint]: doesn't work
\begin{document}
  \section{Some section title}
  \subsection{Some subsection title}
\begin{equation}
   F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: We don't know what you did, what code you are trying to compile, which engine you are using, what the log does say, whether package versions differ, whether font versions differ, whether there are warnings concerning missing fonts .... Not that I would be likely able to help anyway. I guess `psfontst1.map` is MikTeX specific. But, somebody might ....

Comment: Could it be that files in the Roaming folder :
 {C:/Users/xavier/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/mnsymbol/MnSymbolD.enc} is somhow not including the correct code?

Comment: The package `MinionPro` doesn't appear to be distributed with TeXLive. Is it a commercial font package? If so, have you tried contacting the vendor for help?

Comment: MinionPro is a MiKTex package based upon the Adobe available fonts MinionPro

Comment: @Xavier_B - Thanks. Since I don't have MikTeX (which runs only on windows, I believe), I wouldn't know it provides a package called `MinionPro`.

Comment: @Mico I don't know what MikTeX provides either. There are *several* `MinionPro.sty` around. Which you need depends on which version of the fonts you have. Those aren't included in the package because they cannot be. I assume you have to install the fonts separately. For traditional compilation, they need to be converted. Moreover, what you get depends on what you have. Full coverage requires you buy the fonts. Partial coverage requires you convert fonts available with Adobe Reader, but only older versions permit this, legally. That is, it is very complicated.